# Why isn't my ASP.NET ListBox populating with results?

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-web-services

I've been working on an ASP.NET project with DynamoDb, I've taken the item from the Db and made it into a new Car object. When I try to populate a ListBox of cars, I don't seem to get any objects in the ListBox.

Here's what I have:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Amazon.DynamoDBv2;
using Amazon.DynamoDBv2.Model;
using Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DocumentModel;


public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private static AmazonDynamoDBClient client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient();
    private static string tableName = "CarTable";
    private static string sampleCarReg = "05-Rn-1964";
    List<car> cars = new List<car>();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



        Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DocumentModel.Table CarTable =     Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DocumentModel.Table.LoadTable(client, tableName);
        GetItemOperationConfig config = new GetItemOperationConfig
        {
        AttributesToGet = new List<string> { "Reg", "Manufactor", "Year",     "Problems" },
            ConsistentRead = true
        };
        Document doc = CarTable.GetItem(sampleCarReg, config);

        string Reg = doc["Reg"].AsString();
        string Manufactor = doc["Manufactor"].AsString();
        string Year = doc["Year"].AsString();
        string Problems = doc["Problems"].AsString();

       // string Model = doc["Model"].AsString();


        car car1 = new car(Reg, Manufactor, Year, Problems);
        cars.Add(car1);

        lblCar.Text = car1.ToString();
        lbxCars.DataSource = cars;

    }
```

Comment: Do you need to set `lbxCars.DisplayMember` and `lbxCars.ValueMember`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the `ListBox`'s `DataSource` property, but you are not specifying the `DataTextField` and `DataValueField`. You need to set which `Car` properties are used in the `ListBox`.

```
// Use what makes sense to you
lbxCars.DataSource = cars;
lbxCars.DataTextField = "Reg";
lbxCars.DataValueField = "Reg";
lbxCars.DataBind();
```

If you would also like to select the first item, then use the `SelectedIndex` property. Of course, be sure to check that your cars list has items first.

```
if (cars.Any())
{
    lbxCars.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response , probably a stupid question here but why am i getting a displaymemeber Error? Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error: 'ListBox' does not contain a definition for 'DisplayMember' and no extension method 'DisplayMember' accepting a first argument of type 'ListBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Just noticed that you're using web forms (which is obvious to me now). Updated to use web forms ListBox properties.